# How can I make YouTube always select 240p?

Tags: youtube

I have a slow broadband connection (256k) and YouTube plays okay with the 240p quality, so I always select 240p.

I've also ticked the "Never play high quality" checkbox and it stays checked. The current video then proceeds to load in 240p but later on, the YouTube videos always revert to 360p (when I change videos or refresh the page, etc.).

How can I fix this? I don't want to be selecting the 240p from the controls bar every time.

Comment: Try YouTube "Feather" Beta http://www.youtube.com/feather_beta "This is an opt-in beta for "Feather" support on YouTube. The "Feather" project is intended to serve YouTube video watch pages with the lowest latency possible. It achieves this by severely limiting the features available to the viewer and making use of advanced web techniques for reducing the total amount of bytes downloaded by the browser. It is a work in progress and may not work for all videos."

Answer (score 1):

From their official [Google support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=91449):

> You can set permanent quality settings in the [Playback Setup menu](https://www.youtube.com/account_playback).

From what I see, you can use the menu to select "I have a slow connection. Never play higher-quality video". While you can't select your desired 240p (possibly because not every video has such a quality available), it should help you save up those bandwidth and load videos at a much faster rate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have went to the PlayBack Setup Menu and selected the slow connection option, yet the youtube videos continue to load in 360p and I have to manually select 240p at the start of every youtube video. Also, the 240p option has been there on every video I've tried to watch on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Use this add-on [Youtube High Definition](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-high-definition/) in case of Mozilla Firefox  and extension
[Magic Actions for YouTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-actions-for-youtube/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif?hl=en) in Google Chrome.